# eslint indent rule not being disabled

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

I'm trying to make prettier and eslint work together i followed this [article](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/eslint-prettier-for-a-consistent-react-codebase-eaa673debb1d) but i'm having an issue with indention rule.. basically i have this `jsx` format

```
const ResponseModule = ({ response }) => (
    <div>
        {response.code === 401 ? (
            <div className="response">
                <div className="response-content">
                    <h1> {response.message} </h1>
                    <button onClick={() => initLogout()}> Login to continue </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) : null}
    </div>
);
```

I received indention errors like this

```
[eslint] Delete `..` [prettier/prettier]
```

Now when i apply the auto fix it becomes this

```
const ResponseModule = ({ response }) => (
  <div>
    {response.code === 401 ? (
      <div className="response">
        <div className="response-content">
          <h1> {response.message} </h1>
          <button onClick={() => initLogout()}> Login to continue </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </div>
);
```

When i hit save (CTRL+S) in vs code it just goes back to the first format and thus giving me the same errors again.. i can't proceed with work..

This is my eslint config

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "no-tabs": 0,
    "indent": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "linebreak-style": [
      "error",
      "windows"
    ],
    "jsx-closing-tag-location": 0,
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      "error",
      {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".jsx"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier"
  ]
}
```

These are the eslint/prettier package related i have

```
"eslint": "^5.3.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.0",
"prettier": "1.14.3",
```

Comment: I don't know VSCode, but it looks like you have set it to autoformat the code on save. So you should either disable the autoformat or configure it to the correct indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable `react/jsx-indent` as well, that rule is enabled by `eslint-config-airbnb`.

Comment: Sir but how.Please inform i need to disable them.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in here is your Prettier might have 4 space and your ESLint might have 2 space indentation configured. You need to make them same.